# Text orientation in a label

Tags: birt

I would like to know if there's a way to rotate of 90° the text in a label of a Birt report.

I didn't find any option in the advanced properties.

Do I have to add some script in the `onRender` part?

I am using Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 2.5.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in BIRT. Although you can write a [plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-BIRT-ExtensionTutorial1/index.html) for that.